# Element-wise subtraction of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have two numpy arrays say 'a' and 'b' having the dimensions (327600,5) and (3,5) respectively. I want to do an element-wise subtraction of the two arrays. How would I go about doing this without a loop?.

When I do a[0] - b I get a (3,5) array. I want to get a (327600,3,5) array as the result after subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a[:, np.newaxis] - b
```

You need to take a view of `a` with an extra length-1 axis in the shape so the axes line up right for broadcasting.